# Get the type of calling ContentPage of a PageRenderer within a ExportRenderer

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, custom-renderer

I have been following this answer in order to tell if me when my Xamarin Page has loaded. https://stackoverflow.com/a/63592259/560476

The rough idea is that once the `PageRenderer` has attached to the Window it will fire the `PageLoaded` message on to the `MessagingCenter` and my `MainPage` that is subscribed to that message will then react.

However the problem with this implementation is that anytime a `ContentPage` triggers `OnAppearing` it will trigger `PageLoaded` to be sent regardless of the `ContentPage` as it applies to them all.

I wonder if it is possible to get the type that is calling the `ExportRenderer` as I could then do something like `MessagingCenter.Send(new object(), $"{typeof(MainPage)}Loaded");` and then I would only be subscribing to the `ContentPage`'s where I want this.

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(ContentPage), typeof(AdvancedPageRenderer))]
namespace MyRunCompanion.Droid.Renderer
{
    public class AdvancedPageRenderer : PageRenderer
    {
        public AdvancedPageRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {
            AutoPackage = false;
        }

        protected override void OnAttachedToWindow()
        {
            base.OnAttachedToWindow();

            MessagingCenter.Send(new object(), "PageLoaded");
        }
    }
}
```

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();

        MessagingCenter.Subscribe<object>(new object(), "PageLoaded", (sender) =>
        {
            // Do something whenever the "PageLoaded" message is received
            Console.WriteLine("Do something whenever the PageLoaded message is received");
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better approach would be to test in the custom renderer and only send the message when the `ContentPage` that is being renderered is a `MainPage` Class (desired class) instance. This can be achieved using `Element` property:

```
protected override void OnAttachedToWindow()
{
    base.OnAttachedToWindow();
    if (Element is MainPage)
        MessagingCenter.Send(new object(), "PageLoaded");
}
```

But if for some reasons you want to stick with what you described in the question then you can use:

```
MessagingCenter.Send(new object(), Element.GetType().Name + "Loaded");
```

Comment: Cheers, new to Xamarin. Going your route would make my `AdvancedPageRenderer` tightly coupled with `MainPage`. I could of just `ExportRenderer(typeof(MainPage)` if I only wanted to use it here. I think I am happy with the overhead(if any?) with all the `ContentPage`'s sending the message and choosing where I need to listen to the message.

Comment: I think yes you could have ExportRenderer to only MainPage nice that you have figured it out, didn't get to my mind I was focusing on your question how to get the type. Altought the  approach described here gives more flexibility to handle other pages inheriting from ContentPage differently, but at the end it a matter of the use case.