# Check if Xamarin's UI has done initialize?

Tags: user-interface, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

My Xamarin app has a grid layout that contains a lot of images & image buttons. All images have property `Aspect="Fill"`, the problem is when I open the app, the app took a few seconds to resize the images before it properly fill the grid, it looks bad. So to hide it, I put a full-screen image on top of all the images, the idea is to hide the ugly resizing until all the images done resizing.

I've tried wait for x seconds like `await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Delay(1000);` but it isn't good for many reasons: e.g if the init time is longer than `Task.Delay(1000)` then it doesn't work at all.

So Is there any way I can check if Xamarin's UI has done initialize?

Comment: "the app took a few seconds to resize the images before it properly fill the grid", what? Really sounds like you are doing something fishy, if the UI takes so long to init. Care to elaborate what exactly you are doing?

Comment: Regrettably, there is no consistent cross-platform way to know that a page is appearing - so XForms doesn't have such an event. On each platform, it is possible to write a custom renderer that does the check. Requires learning how to write custom renderers, and learning what event or method each platform has that is useful for this purpose. See [Event when Xamarin page is FULLY loaded?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63592259/199364) for an example.

Comment: @Cheesebaron : I exaggerated it, it feels like "a few seconds" but it only happens like half a second, the point is the user can see the UI resizing process.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve : Thank you, I got it, so if I want to do it, I have to implement it for each platform.

Comment: If you are testing with **debugger attached** and/or testing on **emulator**, then it will take longer. Download to a device, then launch app from device's home page. See what it is like there. If still too slow, then you likely have images at much higher resolution than needed, for the size you are showing them. Consider making smaller "thumbnails". I think nuget `Xamarin.FFImageLoading` has options to cache images at a specified size. Calculate a size appropriate to the device, then set Image.HeightRequest. Then would only be slow the first time the image is loaded.